# How to speed up nested for loop with dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','C','D','b','b','D','c','c','c'], 'text':['a','x','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']})
```

Using the following for-loop I can add `x` to a new_col. This for-loop works fine for the small dataframe. However, for dataframes that have thousands of rows, it will take many hours to process. Any suggestions to speed it up?

```
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    if row['id'] == 'C':
        if test['id'][index+1] =='D':
            test['new_col'][index+1] = test['text'][index]
```

[image]

Comment: Please add result as text instead of image

Comment: It is always a bad idea to iterate through a pandas DataFrame.  Their documentation even warns of this.  You would be happier if you pre-processed the data before converting it to a DataFrame.

Comment: `98%` of the times `for-loop` is bad and not to be used with `Pandas`. Avoid it at all costs! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `shift()` and conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'C', 'D', 'b', 'b', 'D', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 
                   'text': ['a', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']})


df['temp_col'] = df['id'].shift()
df['new_col'] = np.where((df['id'] == 'D') & (df['temp_col'] == 'C'), df['text'].shift(), "")
del df['temp_col']
print(df)
```

We can also do it without a temporary column. (Thanks& credits to Prayson )

```
df['new_col'] = np.where((df['id'].eq('D')) & (df['id'].shift().eq('C')), df['text'].shift(), "")
```

Comment: This is cool! We don't need temporary column `df['new_col'] = np.where((df['id'].eq('D')) & (df['id'].shift().eq('C')), df['text'].shift(), "")`